# Form isn't showing select dropdown after validation error

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my form, I generate the select options from my MySQL data table. But when I submit the form without any value, it returns to a blank page and does not show any validation error. When I select a value and submit the form, it inserts the value to MySQL table. No MySQL or PHP error is thrown. I am assuming the problem is the query for the select option is not running. But if it is the problem, what should be the good practice to avoid this problem?
My form is:

```
<?php
   require 'db.php';
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $ad_di = "";
       $ad_di_err = "";
   
       if (empty(trim($_POST["ad_di"]))) {
           $ad_di_err = "District cannot be empty.";
       } else {
           $ad_di = trim($_POST["ad_di"]);
       }
   
       if (empty($ad_di_err)) {
           $sql = "INSERT INTO address (ad_di) VALUES (?)";
           if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
               $stmt->bind_param("i", $p_ad_di);
               $p_ad_di = $ad_di;
               if ($stmt->execute()) {
                   $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                   header("location: add.php?id=$id&update=success");
               }
               $stmt->close();
           } 
       }
   }
   ?>
<form id="acEdit" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" class="contact-form">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>District</label>
            <select name='ad_di' id='ad_di' class='custom-select'>
               <option value=''>Select one ...</option>
               <?php
                  $qDistrict = "SELECT * FROM districts order by name ASC";
                  echo "<select name='ad_di' id='ad_di' class='custom-select'><option value=''>Select one ...</option>";
                  foreach ($mysqli->query($qDistrict) as $rowDistrict) {
                      echo "<option value={$rowDistrict['id']}>{$rowDistrict['name']}</option>";
                  }
                  echo "</select>";
                  ?>
            </select>
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $ad_di_err; ?></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The above query for select options returns as following when the page is loaded first,

```
<select name="ad_di" id="ad_di" class="custom-select">
   <option value="">Select one ...</option>
   <option value="28">Dist A</option>
   <option value="11">Dist B</option>
   <option value="35">Dist C</option>
   <option value="33">Dist D</option>
</select>
```

But when the validation error occurs, the returning page doesn't have any options, just returns

```
<select name="ad_di" id="ad_di" class="custom-select">
   <option value="">Select one ...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try <option value='{$rowDistrict['id']}'> with quotes. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @wayneOS Thanks, but still it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe your form-actoin is somehow faulty. try action="/" instead of action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"

Comment: @wayneOS, The form works with normal input fields or select field but when I add this district select dropdown that takes the options form MySQL table, it stops to work.

Comment: Well then there is something wrong with the data that gets echoed. check your database if the values of id and name are all valid. Best thing to do is that you will echo them before your form to see if the data isn't the problem.

Comment: It doesn't help asking the same question twice

Comment: @B001ᛦ, The first question was closed so I reached again with details of the project. But yet, no solution.

Comment: @wayneOS, Thanks for your time. I checked the data and values but found no issue, nor any hint why this is happening.

Comment: When it's closed it is asking you to edit. Don't repost questions.

Comment: @Dharman, thanks. But I have deleted that one already.

Comment: @Hijibiji Could you update your question and show what Data you get from your Mysql-Select?

Comment: @wayneOS, Please see the edit.

Comment: @Hijibiji Thanks. But it seems all right. But i just noticed that you have an echo after your SELECT query wich will print a second <select>. Remove that echo and try again.

Comment: @wayneOS, that was my main concern. It had been working fine with all other input. field. Why not this one? I removed the </select> echo. Still the same problem.

Comment: @Hijibiji Ok...very strange. Try removing the header("location: add.php?id=$id&update=success"); line.